# Faster growing busy beaver function

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Standard busy beaver function draws attention to final count of nonzero symbols on tape. We could instead look at largest amount of nonzero symbols appearing on tape at *any* point of computation. This function's lower bound would be $\Sigma(n)$ and upper bound would be $S(n)$ (max shifts function). Was there made any research on such functions? If so, are there any known values for this?

Comment: its likely just as hard as [BB fn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) which is uncomputable. one could also count the total # of 1's ever written, etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose there is a machine using $n$ states which, at some point, has $X$ nonzero symbols on the tape. One can build a machine with $O(n)$ states which simulates a run of the original machine with a tape alphabet of three symbols $\{0,1,2\}$, with the following small change: whenever the original machine changes $1$ to $0$, the new machine changes it to $2$; whenever the tape is read, $2$ is interpreted as $0$. The new machine ends up with $Y \in [X,2X]$ nonzero symbols on the tape (we get $\Theta(X)$ instead of $X$ since the simulation requires using two symbols for each original symbol). So your new function, let's call it $F(n)$, satisfies $B(n) \leq F(n) \leq B(O(n))$.

Comment: Is there any way to sharpen the $O()$ and $\Theta()$? Just curiosity (probably best left to the OP)

Comment: I have no idea. My guess is that on the scale from $B(n)$ to $B(O(n))$, $F(n)$ is closer to the latter. It may be possible to prove a lower bound on $F(n)$ somehow. Give it a try!

Answer (score 5):

Your function (call it $F$) obviously satisfies $$\Sigma(n) \le F(n) \le space(n)$$ where $space(n)$ is the maximum number of tape squares visited by any $n$-state halting TM in the same class as those considered in the definition of $\Sigma$. Furthermore, $$space(n) \le \Sigma(3n-1)$$
as proved in the following paper:

Ben-Amram, A. M., B. A. Julstrom, and K. Zwick. "[A Note on Busy Beavers and Other Creatures](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01192693)." Mathematical Systems Theory 29.4 (1996).

Therefore $$\Sigma(n) \le F(n) \le \Sigma(3n-1)$$